# rails _changed? method not working after form update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the following code in my update function. I see that the data is updated in the database, but the 'ship_date_changed?' function doesn't return true.

```
def update
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
ship_date_changed = @order.ship_date_changed?

respond_to do |format|
  if @order.update(order_params)
    OrderNotifier.shipped(@order).deliver if ship_date_changed
    format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: "Your order has been updated" }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it isn't changed. Look at what you do:

```
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
ship_date_changed = @order.ship_date_changed?
```

You get an order out of the database and immediately ask if its ship date has changed. No, it's still exactly the same as the record you got out of the database!

What you probably want to do is slightly change the order of operations:

```
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
@order.attributes = order_params
ship_date_changed = @order.ship_date_changed?

respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save(order_params)
  OrderNotifier.shipped(@order).deliver if ship_date_changed
```

Comment: I've added the line you suggested, and I'm still getting the same behavior. Everything updates fine, but I still cannot get the flag to be true.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the method I used saved the item too soon - see my edit